# min() arg is an empty sequence, what to to if no number goes into my def

Tags: python, sequence

Hi I have a problem with my code and I don't know how to solve it. The challenge is :"How many consecutive numbers are needed?" ... to fill an array. Example: [1, 2, 4, 6] the answer should be 2.
This is what I got.

```
def consecutive(arr):
    arr.sort()
    minimum = min(arr)
    maximum = max(arr)

    diff = maximum - minimum - len(arr) + 1

    return diff
```

the proble is when arr is [] then it doesnt work. What can I change about my code.

Comment: add a condition if `arr` is empty

Comment: I don't understand the logic- can you explain a bit? sorting the array is pointless here, either take the first and last element of the sorted list or apply max/min

Comment: `max()`/`min()` has a `default` arg to handle empty iterables

Answer (score 1):

You can only compute the minimum and maximum of a non-empty list, so you have two alternatives: raise an exception if the input is empty, or *provide* a default value to return in the case of an empty list. (Both cases defer to the caller to decide what is needed if the list is empty, rather than forcing the function to guess at an appropriate value.)

1. Raise an exception.

   ```
   def consecutive(arr):
       if not arr:
           raise ValueError("List is empty")

       minimum = min(arr)
       maximum = max(arr)

       diff = maximum - minimum - len(arr) + 1

       return diff
   ```
2. Provide a default

   ```
   def consecutive(arr, if_empty=None):
       if not arr:
           return if_empty

       minimum = min(arr)
       maximum = max(arr)

       diff = maximum - minimum - len(arr) + 1

       return diff
   ```

---

Note that in neither case do you have to sort the list first; both `min` and `max` handle unsorted lists just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am reading too much into the question, but the answers provided so far, as well as the OP's own answer, are wrong if `arr` has repeated elements such as `[1,2,2,6]`. So the correct answer, 'borrowing'' error handling code from @chepner, is

```
def consecutive(arr):
    if not arr:
        raise ValueError("List is empty")

    minimum = min(arr)
    maximum = max(arr)

    diff = maximum - minimum - len(set(arr)) + 1

    return diff
```

Here `set(arr)` returns unique elements of `arr`